# why setting margin to zero on body tag, cut off the SVG from top and left?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a SVG which is cutting out from top and left side when I set margin to 0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/saurabhkanswal/scdugjwL/

Comment: probably because half of the stroke falls outside the svg canvas. Try a smaller rx ry OR a different viewBox. Try viewBox="-1 -1 102 102" .  In this moment you have overflow:visible so you can see the part of the cirvcle that falls outside. When margin:0  you loose the top and left part of the overflow.